# PictureBox stops adding images

Tags: vb.net, image, backgroundworker, picturebox

I am using a worker thread to load .png images (from a path string) into a global PictureBox2 object, and then exit the _RunWorkerCompleted to use the PictureBox2's width and height for additional work in the method called processpic2.  Everything works fine until about the 5th or 6th images were added to the PB.  A this point, in the processpic2 method, an exception is thrown since the image property of the PictureBox2 evaluates to nothing.

Why would a PB stop taking images after a while?

```
Public Class Form1  
Public WithEvents BackgroundWorker1 As New System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker

Private Sub BackGroundworker1_DoWork(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.DoWork
   Dim args As ArgumentType = e.Argument
   PictureBox2.Image = Nothing
   PictureBox2.Invalidate()
   Dim img As Image
   Using str As Stream = File.OpenRead(args._pathstr)
      img = Image.FromStream(str)
   End Using
   PictureBox2.Image = img
   e.Result = "done"
End Sub

Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs) _Handles BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerCompleted
   'Called when the BackgroundWorker is completed.
   processpic2()
End Sub

Sub btnLoadPicture(pathstr)
   Dim args As ArgumentType = New ArgumentType()
   args._pathstr = pathstr
   BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync(args)
End Sub

Sub processpic2()
   If PictureBox2.Image Is Nothing Then MsgBox("Image is Nothing")
End Sub
```

Comment: Don't processes UI elements from the background worker, that's why... Use a delegate and invoke... The picture box is on a different thread than the background worker...

Comment: I don't think I need to answer this hence why the comment. Look into invoke for the UI control you are working with that will get you in the right direction. If you still need help please update your question and we would be glad to help you.

Comment: I concur with Zaggler. You could possibly return the loaded image in `RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs` (i.e. `e.Result`) and set `PictureBox.Image` in RunWorkerCompleted.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I have used invoke to add icons to a treenode, so will look into that.

Answer (score 0):

The whole point of a `BackgroundWorker` is to do background work.  Making changes to the UI is the exact opposite of background work.  It is foreground work.  If your task is to clear the current contents of a `PictureBox`, load an image from a file and then display that image, only the middle step is background work so only the middle step should be done in the `DoWork` event handler.  The first step should be done before you call `RunWorkerAsync` and the last step should be done in the `RunWorkerCompleted` event handler.

Having said all that, why use a `BackgroundWorker` at all in this case?  Why not simply call the `LoadAsync` method of the `PictureBox` itself?

Comment: Thanks - was unaware of a `LoadAsync` method for a `PictureBox` so will look into that.  One thing is for sure, the images are about 600 x 400 pixel .png's and even when setting `PictureBox1.Image = Nothing`, the Picture box tends to hang at after loading and viewing about 5-8 images.  It seems that some memory contents is getting filled up or something.   `PictureBox1.Invalidate` and `PictureBox1.Image = Nothing` are not helping eradicate this peculiarity.

Comment: An `Image` is a disposable object.  If you're creating an `Image` object and assigning it to the `Image` property of a `PictureBox`, you should be calling `Dispose` on that `Image` object when you're done with it.

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION - thanks to the suggestions received, and what I found on MSDN regarding the `LoadAsync` method of `PictureBox` the following code solved the issue:

```
PictureBox2.Image = Nothing

PictureBox2.WaitOnLoad = False

' Load the image asynchronously.
PictureBox2.LoadAsync(pathstr)
```